# i am getting error like mysql_connect() acces denied for system@localhost(using password NO)

Tags: php

```
class MySQLDatabase
{
    public $connection;
    function _construct() { $this->open_connection();}
    public function open_connection()
    {$this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
        if(!$this->connection){die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());}
        else{$db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$this->connection);
            if(!$db_select){die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());    }
        }}
          public function close_connection({  if(isset($this->connection)){
            mysql_close($this->connection); unset($this->connection);}}
    public function query(/*$sql*/){ $sql = "SELECT*FROM users where id = 1";
        $result = mysql_query($sql); $this->confirm_query($result);
        //return $result;while( $found_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
         echo $found_user ['username'];
        }

    }
    private function confirm_query($result)
    {
        if(!$result)
        {
            die("The Query has problem" . mysql_error());
        }
    }

}

$database = new MySQLDatabase();
$database->open_connection();
$database->query();
$database->close_connection();

?>
```

Comment: Please edit and ask an actual question.

Comment: I formatted your code, you owe me, like, 600 chr(32)s.

Comment: i am new and i dont know how to format the code thnx for formatting i really appreciate it

Comment: @user309381 : when you are on the form to ask or edit a question, there is an orange **?** on the top of the edit box ; click on it, and you'll arrive on the page that describes the syntax you can use to write on stackoverflow : http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in different forms. But two things to make sure - make sure you didn't close the connection before the query and make sure the link didn't go away. With the original mysql extension this sometimes happens. Testing for this can be done by "get_resource_type" - if the connection isn't of type mysql link, you need to reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

'Access denied' means you are connecting to the DB server properly, but the user/host combination you're connecting as (and from) does not have permission to access the server and/or specified database. You can check the permissions from within the mysql monitor with `show grants for user@hostname` (e.g. whatever your DB_USER and DB_PASS defines are).

Remember that MySQL's user system is completely seperate from the operating system's user system, so having a login account on the server does not automatically grant you an account in MySQL.

Full docs on the permissions granting system are [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) on [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html).

edit:

You should NEVER connect to the server as root. Create a new database user with just enough privileges you need on whatever database(s) are required. Connecting as root is just asking for trouble, including possibly opening your server up to remote compromises.

Unless your web app requires modifying tables on-the-fly, something like this should be enough permissions for most everything to work just fine:

```
GRANT insert,select,update,delete on somedatabase.* TO username@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';
```

And then use `DB_USER = 'username'` and `DB_PASS = 'somepassword'` in your connection

That all being said, have you verified that `DB_USER`, `DB_PASS`, and `DB_SERVER` are properly set inside your class? Also note that for MySQL's purposes, combinations of user@host are considered distinct accounts. 'root@localhost' and 'root@127.0.01' may really be the same thing, but MySQL considers them utterly seperate and distinct.

Comment: Don't forget that it could also mean that the selected user needs a password, and you're not passing one

Comment: I check show grants root@localhost and it shows grant ALL root. what is need to be done

Comment: i set the password but still getting the same error.what should i do to solve the error because i tried so hard please help me out

Comment: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'SYSTEM'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\wamp\www\photo_gallery\includes\database.php  on line 56

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in C:\wamp\www\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 56
The Query has problemAccess denied for user 'SYSTEM'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Try skipping on your constant DB_USER/DB_PASS/DB_SERVER, and try hardcoding the relevant values in the connect() call. If that works, then you've got a scoping issue, or are not setting the constants properly.

Comment: Oh, and of course, you're saying "Access denied for user 'SYSTEM'", but are checking permissions for user 'root'. Please make sure you're actually using the correct usernames before you start flooding this site with multiple copies of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you populated the DB_SERVER, _NAME, _USER, _PASS?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. On certain MySQL drivers(particularly on OS X, IIRC), `localhost` actually refers to a socket connection instead of the local system.

Answer (score 0):

In my configuration.php file on the line

```
public $dbtype = 'mysqli';
```

Just use "`mysql`" instead of "`mysqli`". It worked for me ;)