# MySQL Connection Error in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have set the password for root and grant all privileges for root.  Why does it say it is denied?

```
****mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'SYSTEM'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\wamp\www\photo_gallery\includes\database.php  on line 56

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in C:\wamp\www\photo_gallery\includes\database.php on line 56

The Query has problemAccess denied for user 'SYSTEM'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Code as follows:

```
<?php
include("DB_Info.php");

class MySQLDatabase
{
    public $connection;
    function _construct()
    {
        $this->open_connection();
    }
    public function open_connection()
    {   
        $this->connection = mysql_connect($DB_SERVER,$DB_USER,$DB_PASS);
        if(!$this->connection)
        {
            die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
        }
        else
        {
            $db_select = mysql_select_db($DB_NAME,$this->connection);
            if(!$db_select)
            {
                die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }
    function mysql_prep($value)
    {
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
             $value = stripslashes($value);
        }
        // Quote if not a number
        if (!is_numeric($value))
        {
            $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'";
        }
        return $value;

    }
    public function close_connection()
    {
        if(isset($this->connection))
        {
            mysql_close($this->connection);
            unset($this->connection);
        }
    }
    public function query($sql)
    {

        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $this->confirm_query($result);
        return $found_user;
    }
    private function confirm_query($result)
    {
        if(!$result)
        {
            die("The Query has problem" . mysql_error());
        }
    }

}

$database = new MySQLDatabase();



?>
```

Comment: Please do not rollback revisions to do with code formatting.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650033/i-am-getting-error-like-mysql-connect-acces-denied-for-systemlocalhostusing-p

Comment: global $DBSERVER,$DBUSER,$DBPASS,$DBNAME;
        $DBSERVER="localhost";
 $DBUSER = "root";
 $DBPASS = "";(there is my password i have set it for)
 $DBNAME="photo_gallery";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing second underscore for [__construct()](http://docs.php.net/language.oop5.decon#language.oop5.decon.constructor) in

```
class MySQLDatabase
{
    public $connection;
    function _construct()
    {
```

explains all the symptoms (mysql**_query** raising the warning, no undefined variable notices, no matter what you do to make the parameters available to `function open_connection()` it doesn't work simply because it's never called, access denied for *system*@localhost because your webserver runs as localsystem and therefore `system` is the default username for the default mysql connection, ...)

When you create a new object via `$database = new MySQLDatabase();` the method _construct() isn't invoked and therefore neither is $this->open_connection() and *therefore*  no value is assigned to the property $connection which remains NULL and *no connection to the mysql server is established*.
Now when you call `$database->query('something');` and there is no database connection mysql_query() tries to establish the default connection as explained at http://docs.php.net/mysql_query:

> resource mysql_query  ( string $query  [, resource $link_identifier  ] )
>
> [...]
> If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. **If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments.** If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated.

---

- Fix the typo in _construct()
- pass $this->connection to mysql_real_escape_string(), mysql_query() and mysql_error()
- make sure `open_connection()` has all the parameters it needs, e.g. `isset($DB_SERVER,$DB_USER,$DB_PASS,$DB_NAME) or die('missing parameters');`
- add some debug output to see whether it has been called at all, e.g. `echo "Debug: this->connection = mysql_connect($DB_SERVER,$DB_USER,$DB_PASS);\n";`
- don't roll your own MySQL class, use one of the gazillion existing classes, preferably one with broader acceptance.

Comment: +1 and I'd give another +1 for "don't roll your own MySQL class" if I could.

Answer (score 3):

You have not defined any of `$DBSERVER`,`$DBUSER`,`$DBPASS` within the current [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

If those variables are in the global scope you must add the following to the functions that uses them:

```
global $DBSERVER,$DBUSER,$DBPASS;
```

If you intended to use the variables defined and then commented in the `open_connection` function you must first uncomment them and then alter the arguments passed to the `mysql_connect` function.

Answer (score 0):

You're connecting as SYSTEM user without password, which obviously is not allowed to connect to MySQL server.

Comment: THERE ARE JUST TWO LIKE ROOT@LOCALHOST AND 127,0...@LOCALHOST THERE IS NO SYSTEM SOMETHING...I HAVE SET THE PASSWORD FOR IT THOUGH

Answer (score 0):

You really should clean up your questions. This is just a re-post of an earlier question you posted.

I believe you have a typo in your code that may be causing your problem. You define your connection paramaters as `$DB_SERVER` and etc., but you're using `$DBSERVER` in your `mysql_connect()` call. You need to add the underscores to the variable names in your connect call.

Comment: ACTUALLY THERE'S NO PARAMATERS ERROR I TRIED JUST TO CHANGE IT. 
define('DB_SERVER','')? null : define("DB_SERVER","localhost");THIS IS IN CONFIG.PHP FILE I M CALLING USING INCLUDE("CONFIG");BUT I DONT KNOW IT DOESNT CALL THIS FILE. WHY I DONT KNOW...PLZ HELP

Comment: For a start, you'd need to do: include("config.php") not just include("config").  And you'll still need to follow Yacoby's advice, above.

Comment: Since there's obviously something wrong with your CapsLock key did you check the variables and passwords? They might be all in caps, too? (Sorry, this isn't helpful at all  ..but I couldn't resist, really sorry)

Comment: i am sorry it's include("config.php") its type mistake

Comment: as i have tried putting user name ,paswwrod in MYSqlDatabase class it does work fine.but if i do it seperate it doesnt work

Comment: Might also want to add the absolute path for the included config: include("/path/to/file/config.php");